# Does all code to be run in a java program need to be in public static void main(String[] args)?

Tags: java

Does all code I want to be executed in a java program need to be in the parentheses after public static void main(String[] args) in the main.java file? Or is this only where execution of the program begins? Can it be anywhere else in the other files in the project folder? Sorry if this is worded poorly I am new to trying to learn Java.

Comment: Main class is where execution of program begins

Comment: @sanjeevRm - Not the "Main class", the class (with any name) that has the main method

Answer (score 0):

When you run java program it will run whats inside `public static void main(String[] args)` method. But body of this method can refere to any file in project folder.

Comment: Ok cool, so there isn't any way to run anything outside of putting it in ```public static void main(String[] args)```?

Comment: @tryingtolearnjava Please define "run anything outside"? Notice that you did not define `String` class but you are able to use it in your code. Same way you can define other types like `package my.types; public class Car { .. }` (placed in `Car.java` file) and use it in your own code like `import my.types.Car` and later `Car myCar = new Car("some", "info", 421, etc);`.

Comment: @Pshemo apologies, I mean writing something like ```system.out.println(".");``` anywhere outside of ```public static void main(String[] args)```. As well is it possible to have two files in a project folder with ```public static void main(String[] args)``` ?

Comment: @tryingtolearnjava Re: "*writing something like `System.out.println(".");` anywhere outside of public static void main(String[] args)*" no, you can't have such statements *anywhere*. Statements can be only inside methods (not only `main` method), constructors or initialization blocks (this may be what you are looking for but I wouldn't go there yet, get a book and let it guide you there). Re: "*is it possible to have two files in a project folder with `.. main..` method*" yes, you can have two separate files holding types and each of those types could hold their own main method.

Comment: @Pshemo, thank you for your replies I definitely understand much better now

Answer (score 0):

Yes and No.
**Yes**: when you start your code with java (or java.exe) command. The java tool will invoke the function `main` and will complain if it is missing.
**No**: You can make your own native executable that will load via JNI and use different method with different name and signature.